# Kotlin: MutableSharedFlow instance is null during emit even for nonNull variable

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, kotlin-sharedflow

I have the following class:

```
internal class TestClass(
     private val someOtherFlow: Flow<String>
) {
    private val scope: CoroutineScope by lazy {
        CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())
    }
    private val testFlow: MutableSharedFlow<String> = MutableSharedFlow()
    init {
        scope.launch {
            someOtherFlow.collect {
                refreshTestFlow()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun refreshTestFlow() {
        scope.launch {
            testFlow.emit(strValue)
        }
    }
}
```

testFlow.emit(strVlue) --> testFlow is giving NullPointerException
even though it is a nonNull variable and instantiated when the `TestClass` is created.

Could someone please help understand why this is happening.
Thanks

I have tried testing this.

Comment: I think you’ve cut out too much code for us to be able to tell. Are you by any chance calling an open function from an init block?  By the way, the lazy creation of the CoroutineScope doesn’t make sense here. Creating a coroutine scope is trivial so there’s no point.

Comment: not calling any open function from init block

Comment: I mean in the superclass, if there is one. That is one of only two ways I think it’s possible to get a null pointer exception with pure Kotlin classes and not using `!!`. The other way is if you have the companion object of a class reference it’s class partner’s child classes.

Comment: I suspect it may be caused by the fact you access the `testFlow` from another thread and you didn't synchronize that access in any way. You could try making it `@Volatile`, however, I think such design where we start background operations while still in the constructor is generally a bad idea and you may get many different kinds of problems.